# Mixing a table with graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt] 
{\node[inner sep=0pt](A-1-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-c}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image}};\\
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-2-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-c}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}};\\
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-3-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-c}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}};\\
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-4-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-4-2){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-4-3){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-4-4){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-c}};\\
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-5-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-5-2){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-5-3){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-5-4){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-c}};\\
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-6-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-6-2){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-6-3){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-6-4){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-c}};\\
};

\node[right=1mm of A, minimum size=8cm] (B) 
{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=12cm]{example-image-a}};

\node[below left =1mm of B.north east, minimum size=3cm] (C) 
{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-b}};

\draw[->,very thick, shorten >=-2mm] (A.south west) -- 
(A.south-|B.east) node[midway, below=8mm] {Time};
\draw[->,very thick, shorten >=-2mm] (A.south west) -- 
(A.north west) node[midway, left=10mm,rotate=90]{Quantity};

\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \t using int(1*\i), 
evaluate=\i as \j using int(5-\i)] in {1,2,3,4}{
\node [below=43mm of A-4-\i] {\t};
\node [left=5mm of A-\i-1] {\j};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

I have two problems during running this code; firstly I added two rows to this code but I couldn't adding the label or the value that indicate each one of these new rows (as you see in the resulted figure), another thing is I want to change the values of x axis to (0,0.5,1,2) rather than (1,2,3,4)
and change the values of y axis to (1,10,50,100,250,500) rather than the old values.(see the attached picture)[image: the relationship between the quantities of a material with time]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the easiest is to just split it in two loops and specify the labels explicitly, i.e.

```
\foreach \i/\t in {1/0,2/0.5,3/1,4/2}
  \node [below=43mm of A-4-\i] {\t};

\foreach \j/\t in {1/500, 2/250, 3/100, 4/50, 5/10, 6/1}
  \node [left=5mm of A-\j-1] {\t};
```

instead of the one `\foreach` you have now.

[image]

By using a `matrix of nodes`, and setting a default size for images, you can reduce the code a bit:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=2cm,height=2cm} % sets default size of images within the tikzpicture
\matrix (A) [column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt,matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt}] 
{\includegraphics{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics{example-image-c}&
\includegraphics{example-image}\\
\includegraphics{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics{example-image-c}&
\includegraphics{example-image}&
\includegraphics{example-image-a}\\
\includegraphics{example-image-c}&
\includegraphics{example-image}&
\includegraphics{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics{example-image-b}\\
\includegraphics{example-image}&
\includegraphics{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics{example-image-c}\\
\includegraphics{example-image}&
\includegraphics{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics{example-image-c}\\
\includegraphics{example-image}&
\includegraphics{example-image-a}&
\includegraphics{example-image-b}&
\includegraphics{example-image-c}\\
};

\node[right=1mm of A, minimum size=8cm] (B) 
{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=12cm]{example-image-a}};

\node[below left =1mm of B.north east, minimum size=3cm] (C) 
{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-b}};

\draw[->,very thick, shorten >=-2mm] (A.south west) -- 
(A.south-|B.east) node[midway, below=8mm] {Time};
\draw[->,very thick, shorten >=-2mm] (A.south west) -- 
(A.north west) node[rotate=90,midway, left=13mm]{Quantity};


\foreach \i/\t in {1/0,2/0.5,3/1,4/2}
  \node [below=43mm of A-4-\i] {\t};

\foreach \j/\t in {1/500, 2/250, 3/100, 4/50, 5/10, 6/1}
  \node [left=5mm of A-\j-1] {\t};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

---

Original code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [column sep=0pt, row sep=0pt] 
{\node[inner sep=0pt](A-1-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-c}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image}};\\
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-2-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-c}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}};\\
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-3-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-c}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}};\\
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-4-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-4-2){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-4-3){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-4-4){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-c}};\\
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-5-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-5-2){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-5-3){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-5-4){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-c}};\\
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-6-1){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-6-2){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-a}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-6-3){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-b}};&
\node[inner sep=0pt](A-6-4){\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{example-image-c}};\\
};

\node[right=1mm of A, minimum size=8cm] (B) 
{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=12cm]{example-image-a}};

\node[below left =1mm of B.north east, minimum size=3cm] (C) 
{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-b}};

\draw[->,very thick, shorten >=-2mm] (A.south west) -- 
(A.south-|B.east) node[midway, below=8mm] {Time};
\draw[->,very thick, shorten >=-2mm] (A.south west) -- 
(A.north west) node[midway, left=13mm,rotate=90]{Quantity};


\foreach \i/\t in {1/0,2/0.5,3/1,4/2}
  \node [below=43mm of A-4-\i] {\t};

\foreach \j/\t in {1/500, 2/250, 3/100, 4/50, 5/10, 6/1}
  \node [left=5mm of A-\j-1] {\t};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```